# Make a full redirect from Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, I have an action that is triggered through a jQuery `AJAX POST request`. In this action, I check some DB data with the attributes, and if it passes the validation, I return a `PartialView` result that is set inside a div on the view in the `success` callback of the jQuery request. What I want to do is, if it does not pass validation, fully redirect the user to another page in my application.

I know I could do this through Javascript by passing a value to the view, and doing an extra check there, but I would like to know if it can be done on server-side.

Comment: AJAX post cannot automatically redirect the page. You have to handle the result in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your contorller action you could return either a `PartialView` or a `JsonResult` pointing to the controller action to redirect to:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (HasPassedValidation)
    {
         // everything went fine => let's return a partial view
         // that will be updated
         return PartialView();
    }

    // something went wrong with the validation => 
    // we return a JsonResult pointing to the controller
    // action we want to redirect to
    var result = new 
    { 
        redirectTo = Url.Action("SomeOtherAction", "SomeController") 
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then inside the success callback of your AJAX call test in which case you are and take respective steps:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.redirectTo) {
        // the controller action returned a JSON result => there was an error
        // => let's redirect
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    } else {
        // everything went fine => let's update the DOM with the partial
        $('#results').html(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Darin, if you say this is the way, then I won't wait for other answers. :) Thanks!

Comment: If I posted this as an answer then this is the way I would implement it based on the problem description you have made in your question. Up to you to decide what to do with your scenario and whether this is adapted to it.

Comment: Yes, it's great! Plus, for me, you've never been wrong so far.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX form control in MVC doesn't do a full redirect. The HTML one does, however. (Though it does mean you lose the async behavior).

Comment: Thanks, got it. Would have been nice to be able to do this, though.

Comment: Yeah. I've had that experience also. Meh.